# small prob with fetching data from text file

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Update : success progress but still a problem : new data reloaded after refreshing the page twice it's ok to refresh the page once every 10 or 15 minutes but one ferfesh doesn't display the new data from the text file though it already contains the new data came from getData.php file

getData.php code

```
$connect = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
$db = mysql_select_db("mydb",$connect);

$getTextQ = "select * from text";
$getTextR = mysql_query($getTextQ);
$path = "text/";
$myfile = $path."data.txt";
$open = fopen($myfile,"w");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($getTextR)){
    $write = fwrite($open,"<div class='slide'><h1>".$row['id']."</h1><p>".$row['desc']."</p></div>");       
}
$close = fclose($open);
mysql_close($connect);
```

index.php code

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
<script src="js/slides.min.jquery.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function(){
            $.ajax({
            url: 'getData.php',
            type: 'POST'
            });
        });         
var txtFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
txtFile.open("GET", "text/data.txt", true);
txtFile.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (txtFile.readyState === 4) {
if (txtFile.status === 200) {
allText = txtFile.responseText;
}
}
}
txtFile.send(null);

    });

</script>
```

html code

```
<div id="mydiv" class="slides_container">                               
<?php $path ="text/"; 
$open = fopen($path."data.txt","r"); 
$read = fread($open,50000); 
$close = fclose($open); 
echo $read; 
?>
</div>
```

Comment: @afuzzyllama Actually they do, in both html4 and html5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not have the php file write to a text file and then read the text file; you are doing two ajax calls / requests to the server where only one is needed.

Apart from that it could lead to errors on the server when two instances try to write at the same file at the same time.

If you change your `getData.php` to echo out the values instead of storing them in a text file, you can simplify your javascript to:

```
$("#myDiv").load("getData.php");
```

Comment: i tried it before it works in the page but not in the slideshow don't know why though the code works when copying it from the text file and paste it inside the div slideshow works normally so the problem is slideshow breaks down if data echoed from the head nothing changes in the code. that's the code http://www.mediafire.com/?36gvbb3o6g3ng6t and that's the text file http://www.mediafire.com/?p45x5jft73tycc5 code is not complicated just a small project of slideshow and 2 php files 2 get data from database save it to a text file and the other to echo data from the text file

Comment: And, there may be a bind issue.

Answer (score 1):

`.ajax` is asynchronous by default. If you call `.ajax` first and expect it to create the text file for the `.load` function that is called next on the same page, set `async: false` in the `.ajax` function.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'getData.php',
    type: 'POST',
    async: false
});
```

Also, might be helpful to add a delay to give your server time to write the text file if that becomes an issue. I don't know how big your text file may become. Example:

```
$("#myDiv").delay(1000).load("text/data.txt");
```

Or, in the succes function as jeroen suggested:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'getData.php',
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(){
        $("#myDiv").load("text/data.txt");
    }
});
```

Comment: ok now divs loaded but hidden for the show but sow is not working when i copy the text file content into the html div, slideshow works but when i grab data from the text file show stops

Comment: @jqbeginner Your show function probably is not bound to the new items loaded. Use jquery `.on` to bind them to the slide class. http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: not working but i have been trying this but php code prevents creating the txt file in the ajax code when commenting php code page loads normally
  $.ajax({
  url: 'getData.php',
  type: 'POST',
  success: function(){
  <?php
  $path ="text/";
  $open = fopen($path."data.txt","r");
  $read = fread($open,500);
  $close = fclose($open); 
  /*<?php echo $read; ?>*/
  ?>   

        document.getElementById("mydiv").innerHTML = "some text";
       }

  });

Comment: ok very close to do it but still alittle problem
i'm using ajax code to read the text file  

var txtFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
txtFile.open("GET", "text/data.txt", true);
txtFile.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (txtFile.readyState === 4) {
if (txtFile.status === 200) {
allText = txtFile.responseText;
}
}
}
txtFile.send(null);

and it's working but can't write the html to the div from the head section it's not working with the slideshow and when i use this

$("#mydiv").html(allText);

inside the div it prints nothing at all can't recall the variable created in the head

Comment: @jqbeginner When are you calling `$("#mydiv").html(allText);`? Have you tried `allText = txtFile.responseText; $("#mydiv").html(allText);`?

Comment: allText = txtFile.responseText; is already in the head section and $("#mydiv").html(allText); can't get the value of the variable in the body section

Comment: code updated ( very simple php and html code just for showing the problem )